# SQL Query and Sort From Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, select

Working with SQL via a NOVA Oracle DB. Need to know how to query from multiple tables and arrange results based on being sorted by the highest values. Here are a few lines of code to reflect the three tables:

```
INSERT INTO VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN,vehicleType,vehicleMake,vehicleModel,vehicleWhereFrom,vehicleWholesaleCost,vehicleTradeID)
VALUES
('147258HHE91K3RT','compact','chevrolet','spark','Maryland',20583.00,NULL);
INSERT INTO VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN,vehicleType,vehicleMake,vehicleModel,vehicleWhereFrom,vehicleWholesaleCost,vehicleTradeID)
VALUES
('789456ERT0923RFB6','Midsize','ford','Taurus','washington, d.c.',25897.22,1);
INSERT INTO VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN,vehicleType,vehicleMake,vehicleModel,vehicleWhereFrom,vehicleWholesaleCost,vehicleTradeID)
VALUES
('1234567890QWERTYUIOP','fullsize','Lincoln','towncar','Virginia',44222.10,NULL);
```

AND

```
INSERT INTO SALES
(saleID,grossSalePrice,vehicleStatus,saleDate,saleMileage,customerID,salespersonID,vehicleVIN)
VALUES
(1,25987.28,'sold',date '2012-10-15',10,1,1,'147258HHE91K3RT');
INSERT INTO SALES
(saleID,grossSalePrice,vehicleStatus,saleDate,saleMileage,customerID,salespersonID,vehicleVIN)
VALUES
(2,29999.99,'sold',date '2012-10-17',50087,2,2,'789456ERT0923RFB6');
INSERT INTO SALES
(saleID,grossSalePrice,vehicleStatus,saleDate,saleMileage,customerID,salespersonID,vehicleVIN)
VALUES
(3,47490.88,'sold',date '2012-11-05',30,3,3,'1234567890QWERTYUIOP');
```

AND

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS
(customerID,customerFirName,customerLasName,customerMiName,customerStreet,customerState,customerCity,customerZip)
VALUES
(1,'Regorna','Trasper','J','11111 Address Way','Maryland','Hollywood','20636');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS
(customerID,customerFirName,customerLasName,customerMiName,customerStreet,customerState,customerCity,customerZip)
VALUES
(2,'Bob','Seagram','A','22222 Seagram Lane','Texas','Houston','77001');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS
(customerID,customerFirName,customerLasName,customerMiName,customerStreet,customerState,customerCity,customerZip)
VALUES
(3,'Sally','Anderson','P','33333 Pheonix Drive','Arizona','Pheonix','85001');
```

Obviously there are other tables that come into play here (salesperson, etc.), however these are the only tables needed for the query. The query I want to pull needs to show the total count of sales for each model, sorted by the highest values, and the total count of sales for each zip code, sorted by the highest values. An example (using the data provided above) would look similar to this:

```
MODEL    NUMBER of SALES    ZIP CODE    NUMBER OF SALES
spark    1                  20636       1  
Taurus   1                  77001       1
towncar  1                  85001       1
```

The results need to be sorted by highest values, based on the number of sales. I'm also trying to accomplish this via a single SELECT query.

I've tried some ideas, but haven't been able to find anything that hits the home run yet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Are you asking how to join tables?

Comment: Will post what I have this evening. I do not have my "worksheet" with all of my trial code at my current machine.

Comment: I'm not too sure if I'm asking how to join tables or not. I've done Inner Joins before, but never with three tables, while two columns pulling data from the same field (ex. vehicleModel and customerZip are pulling data based on the total number of sales).

My thoughts are that I need to first count the number of total sales, and somehow work that into a joined table which contains the vehicleModel and customerZip fields, sorted by the highest number of sales. I just can't put my finger on how to do so, especially while keeping it in a single SELECT command.

Comment: The total count per model is different from the total count per zip code. You are showing result rows with both model and zip codes, but if you select a total for a model there are possibly multiple zip codes involved, and if you select a total for a zip code there are probably multiple models involved. So your description doesn't match the sample result. Please think this over and tell us what you are really after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you're after:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.VEHICLEMODEL, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.VEHICLEVIN) "CAR_SALES" 
,  c.CUSTOMERZIP, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.CUSTOMERZIP )"TOTAL_SALES_AT_ZIP" 
FROM SALES s, VEHICLES v, CUSTOMERS c
WHERE s. VEHICLEVIN = v. VEHICLEVIN
and  c. CUSTOMERID = s. CUSTOMERID    
ORDER BY 2 DESC , 4 DESC
```

Comment: You're awesome! Never would have thought to do it this way (incorporating the partitions). Fantastic! THANK YOU!